# get maximum length of JavaScript array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have the following array :

```
array = ['a', 'abcde', 'ab'] ;
```

I would like to get the maximum length of the array elements ie 5 (for the element 'abcde').

I know that you can get the length of an array element via (eg) array[1].length but I don't know how to get the maximum length.

Any answer in JavaScript or jQuery would be great.

TIA

Paul Jones

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. All the solutions worked perfectly with the example I gave, where all the array elements are strings.
For anyone who is interested, a slight addition has to be made (I think) if the array elements are numeric :

$.each(myarray, function(i, item)
{
  item = String(item)   // addition
  maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, item.length);
  alert(item + ' ' + maxLength)
});

If there is a 'smarter' way of doing this, let me know.

Thanks again for the help

Paul Jones

Answer (score 25):

One-liner for you:

```
 Math.max.apply(Math, $.map(array, function (el) { return el.length }));
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5SDBx/**

You can do it without jQuery in newer browsers (or even older browsers with a [compatibility implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) of `Array.prototype.map`) too:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(function (el) { return el.length }));
```

Comment: Heh, I was just about to write exactly that line, although possibly without jQuery.

Comment: @Tim Without jQuery? *Are you mad?* :P

Comment: @Tim: yeah, thought about it but IE8 and lower made me think again :-) *edit:* added.

Comment: You already had your +1. What do I do now? Have a "well done". Well done.

Answer (score 15):

A new answer to an old question: in ES6 you can do even shorter:

```
Math.max(...array.map(el => el.length));
```

Answer (score 5):

One (possibly rubbish) way of doing that, without using Jquery:

```
var myarray = ['a','abcde','ab'];
var maxlen = 0;
for (i=0; i<myarray.length; i++) {
  if (myarray[i].length>maxlen) {
    maxlen = myarray[i].length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with a good old for loop, likely it's faster than other solutions. You might test for a native *each* method first though.

Comment: Judging by the downvote received, I guess self-deprecation isn't a good idea on here. Good idea about the each though.

Comment: It is possible to convert this to self contained expression using `Array.reduce`.

Answer (score 5):

In such cases, there is a very useful function.
 [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
['a', 'abcde', 'ab'].reduce((r,s) => r.length > s.length ? r : s, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `Array.prototype.reduce()`, you can elegantly perform a `Math.max()` calculation for each item in the array. It does not matter whether the items in the array are string or sub-arrays (2D array, matrix, etc.), this will work because `String` and `Array` both have a `prototype.length()` function.

I also added a check for integer values per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043471/get-maximum-length-of-javascript-array-element/28634941#comment7020537_6043501) above.

```js
function arrayItemMax(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (result, val) {
        return Math.max(result, !isNaN(val) ? parseInt(val) : val.length);
    }, 0);
}

function print(text) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += text + '<br />';
}

print(arrayItemMax(['a', 'abcde', 'ab'])); // 5
print(arrayItemMax([1, 5, 2]));            // 5
print(arrayItemMax(['1', '5', '2']));      // 5
```

One liner:

```
function(a){return a.reduce(function(r,v){return Math.max(r,!isNaN(v)?parseInt(v):v.length);},0);}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery's [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate a little nicer.

```
var maxLength = 0;

$.each(array, function(i, item) {
   maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, item.length);
});
```

Or plain ol' JavaScript...

```
var maxLength = 0;

for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
   maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, array[i].length);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies - all the solutions worked perfectly. For anyone who is interested, a slight addition has to be made if the array elements are numeric :

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that.

I would iterate through all the array elements and store the longest element in a local variable. You get the longest element by comparing the first array element with the second, then storing the longer one. Then go on and compare each element with the longest one so far.

You just need one loop to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create own your code.
Follow this ->

```
Array.prototype.count = function(){  return this.length; }
```

then use

```
arr = [ "erhan",1,"sonmez",2 ];
arrCount = arr.count();
```